# HTML tags not shown in result captured from PHP regular expression

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am trying to extract everything inside the `<HostProperties`> tag. I use this regex in python and it works fine but when I use this regex in PHP it ignores every other tag inside the `<HostProperties>` tag and gives the output shown below.

My input is:

```
<HostProperties>
<tag name="cpe-1">cpe:/a:microsoft:iis:8.5</tag>
<tag name="HOST_END">Fri May  6 07:15:32 2016</tag>
<tag name="LastUnauthenticatedResults">1462533332</tag>
<tag name="Credentialed_Scan">false</tag>
<tag name="policy-used">Advanced Scan</tag>
<tag name="patch-summary-total-cves">16</tag>
<tag name="cpe">cpe:/o:microsoft:windows</tag>
<tag name="os">windows</tag>
<tag name="cpe-0">cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2012:r2::datacenter</tag>
<tag name="system-type">general-purpose</tag>
<tag name="operating-system">Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter</tag>
<tag name="mac-address">34:40:b5:a1:be:8a</tag>
<tag name="traceroute-hop-0">172.23.144.5</tag>
<tag name="host-ip">172.23.144.5</tag>
<tag name="netbios-name">PKLHODC03</tag>
<tag name="HOST_START">Fri May  6 07:05:56 2016</tag>
</HostProperties>
```

My PHP regex code:

```
 preg_match_all("#(?<=(<HostProperties>))((?:.|\n)*?)(?=</HostProperties)#s", $reading, $host_properties);


                    echo "<pre>";

                    var_dump($host_properties[2]);

                    echo "</pre>";

                    echo "<br>";
```

My output is:

```
cpe:/a:microsoft:iis:8.5
Fri May  6 07:15:32 2016
1462533332
false
Advanced Scan
16
cpe:/o:microsoft:windows
windows
cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2012:r2::datacenter
general-purpose
Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter
34:40:b5:a1:be:8a
172.23.144.5
172.23.144.5
172.23.144.5
172.23.144.5
PKLHODC03
Fri May  6 07:05:56 2016
```

My expected output is:

```
 <tag name="cpe-1">cpe:/a:microsoft:iis:8.5</tag>
 <tag name="HOST_END">Fri May  6 07:15:32 2016</tag>
 <tag name="LastUnauthenticatedResults">1462533332</tag>
 <tag name="Credentialed_Scan">false</tag>
 <tag name="policy-used">Advanced Scan</tag>
 <tag name="patch-summary-total-cves">16</tag>
 <tag name="cpe">cpe:/o:microsoft:windows</tag>
 <tag name="os">windows</tag>
 <tag name="cpe-0">cpe:/o:microsoft:windows_server_2012:r2::datacenter</tag>
 <tag name="system-type">general-purpose</tag>
 <tag name="operating-system">Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2    Datacenter</tag>
 <tag name="mac-address">34:40:b5:a1:be:8a</tag>
 <tag name="traceroute-hop-0">172.23.144.5</tag>
 <tag name="host-ip">172.23.144.5</tag>
 <tag name="netbios-name">PKLHODC03</tag>
 <tag name="HOST_START">Fri May  6 07:05:56 2016</tag>
```

Why is my output different from what I expect?

Comment: I think you're mistaken on that output. But try `'~(?<=<HostProperties>).*?(?=</HostProperties)~s'` and just print `$host_properties[0]`

Comment: Are you viewing the output in a web browser? Those tags are probably getting interpreted by the browser instead of being shown, as if they were HTML.

Comment: Use `"#<HostProperties>(.*?)</HostProperties>#s"`, and `print_r($matches[1])`. No need for lookarounds. Then, consider using DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The `<pre>` tag [does not prevent markup from being rendered](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre):

> **Note:** you will need to escape any contained '`<`' characters as '`&lt;`' to make sure enclosed code is not interpreted as markup.

Since you are using PHP the [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function may prove useful here:

```
echo "<pre>";
echo htmlspecialchars($host_properties[2]);
echo "</pre>";
```